# "after/since the outbreak" or "during the [current] outbreak"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The definition of outbreak given by [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/outbreak?q=outbreak) is

- the sudden start of something unpleasant, especially violence or a disease

While that given for a [pandemic](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pandemic_1) is

- a disease that spreads over a whole country or the whole world

Those definitions suggest that an outbreak is a relatively momentary event whereas a pandemic is a prolonged one, and that an outbreak can occur without necessarily leading to a pandemic – that is, the disease gets nipped in the bud – just as a pandemic can occur without the disease having necessarily "broken out" – that is, without the disease having had a "sudden start".

Yet, it seems, from the similar number of Google Search results for the phrases "after the outbreak", "since the outbreak" and "during the outbreak", that "outbreak" is being used as a synonym of "pandemic". Isn't that usage incorrect?

Comment: The problem is that, while "outbreak" technically means the start of an epidemic, it is often used to refer to the entire period of the epidemic, or at least a substantial part of it during its start.  This isn't "incorrect", it's simply business as usual for the English language.

Answer (score 2):

Well spotted. Although OED doubtless lists many subsenses, it's not easy to find an online justification for this usage, even though we know all too well at the moment that it's common.

[*Study.com*](https://study.com/academy/lesson/disease-outbreak-definition-types.html) has the following [emphasis mine]:

> *An **outbreak** is defined as anytime there are more cases of a disease*
>   *than expected in a specific area. Since mumps [for instance is]*
>   *extremely rare, thanks to vaccines, only a handful of cases in a city*
>   *would constitute an outbreak.*

The [WHO](https://www.who.int/environmental_health_emergencies/disease_outbreaks/en/) definition is virtually identical.

And rather simplistically, any number of cases of COVID-19 is more than were expected a few months ago (it was unknown).

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/outbreak) gives the usual inchoative (in the general 'pertaining to a beginning' sense) definition, but includes an example sentence that shows a durative usage:

> **outbreak** ... noun [countable]
>        if there is an outbreak of fighting or disease in an area, it suddenly starts to happen: *a cholera outbreak*
>
> Examples from the Corpus
>
> • By 1946 the worst epidemic of poliomyelitis since the 1916 outbreak
>   gripped the United States.

Dictionaries aren't infallible ... as we see, not even entirely consistent. It's best to check more than one. In depth.